# Css position a child div alignment by using offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to find the position of the parent div i.e (first Div) and place the child div i.e second div on top of the parent div by using offset.i.e I dynamically need to calculate the parent div and position the child div's top and left using offset. I am new to jquery. Can anyone please help me with this.

Code: Please find the link here
http://jsbin.com/lemaduxosi/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent DIV: `position: relative`
Child DIV: `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`

When the child element has `position: absolute`, its coordinates are relative to its offset parent.  By default, the `body` is an offset parent, but setting `position: relative` on the Parent DIV causes it to become an offset parent.

Comment: @David Thomas But be aware that in your example .second is a sibbling of .first and not a child.

Comment: Thanks , but this does not seem to work, so i would want to find the offset of the first div and then calculate the left and right and provide the position for the second div. Can anyone please help me on that